# TPU V4 Runtime Error: SliceBuilder detects hardware error

Tags: google-compute-engine, tpu

I've been running some jax code successfully on a tpu v4-64 slice. However, my slice was preempted and when I recreated the same size slice I am now running into the following error :

> "RuntimeError: Unable to initialize backend 'tpu': INTERNAL:
> SliceBuilder detects hardware error and is stopping TPU slice. (set
> JAX_PLATFORMS='' to automatically choose an available backend)".

The jax code has not changed between the old and new slice. I tried again to recreate a new v4-64 slice but encountered the same error. The error also always occurs on worker 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried

- recreating the slice
- launching the command on each worker separately vs using --all-workers

Comment: Are you using `tpu-ubuntu2204-base` image: https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/run-calculation-jax#create-vm

Could you test with extra arguments `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 TPU_STDERR_LOG_LEVEL=0 TPU_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0`